# How to format tag in Developer CV?

Tags: discussion, support

My question is about formatting on Developer CV How can i format the tag`java` as Java and `spring` as Spring. Since I know I dont have reputation and also authority to that but when I review my cv

> Technical Skills Likes: java, android, java-ee, jsf, cdi, servlet, jsp, jstl, ejb

Well, does this follow the pattern of cv or not? Does this reject my cv as not being formatted properly? If so how can I formatted it properly?

Comment: [Tags are always lowercase.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216225/194720)